# Fedora Linux ISO less than 1GB?

Tags: fedora

I'm Developing a deployment tool for deploying apps to fedora. When I went to the fedora  website to download, I saw the image was around 2GB. Is there any fedora respins which are less than 1GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Server netinst ISO](https://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/fedora/linux/releases/36/Server/x86_64/iso/) is less than 700 MiB. But these images need internet access to download packages during the installation. [Cloud images](https://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/fedora/linux/releases/36/Cloud/x86_64/images/) (usable also for virtualization) are even smaller, around 300 to 400 MiB.

Smallest "full" Live ISO is probably for LXDE which is around 1400 MiB.

Answer (score 1):

That are < 1GB, no. Closest is 1.4GB (LXDE or LXQt) unless you want the netinstaller, which is 600MB.